# Challenges in switching tense

Tags: fiction, tenses

I am writing fiction and considering using past tense by default but then switching to present tense for action scenes.

[This answer](https://writers.stackexchange.com/a/12242/10949) leads me to believe switching tense can be done. I assume that changing tense needs to be done carefully not to confuse the reader, but what other challenges are there in changing tense, and how can these challenges be over come?

Are there any recent literary classics that employ a similar style?

Comment: @LaurenIpsum Thanks for pointing me in the direction of that question, my google-fu was failing me it seems. I have changed the question slightly so it is no longer a duplicate.

Comment: Closed as duplicate. The original question doesn't ask specifically about confusing the reader; that's just the most common answer given. So you're still repeating the same question, but asking for different (more varied?) answers. The right way to do that is to offer a bounty on the original question.